# Orientation on Poincaré disc

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to know what are the standard orientation of the Poincaré disc and the upper half plane? Is it just the induced orientation of $\mathbb R^2$ i.e. the pull back of the standard orientation form of $\mathbb R^2$ via the inclusion map?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb C$ is oriented by declaring $1,i$ to be a positively-oriented basis for the real vector space.